# Как игнорировать \n в java

Tags: java, классы

Я начал изучать язык java. В первом своем задании мне нужно просто создать класс, потом создать массив элементов класса и в итоге его вывести. Всё шло хорошо, но вот возникла одна проблемка.

Код программы:
https://onlinegdb.com/yKS73iKRx

(Ps. Я выложил код на онлайн компиляторе, потому что здесь я не  смог его никак оформить, сайт постоянно жалуется на не правильно оформленный фрагмент кода.)

При вводе первой книги всё нормально, но при вводе второй ввод 'Автора' просто пропускает.
Консоль:

```
>Введите количество книг: 2
>
>Введите автора книги: Пушкин
>
>Введите количество страниц: 150
>
>Введите тираж: 234
>
>Введите год издания: 12421
>
>Некорректное значение года. Кажется, что вы ввели книгу из будущего:)
>
>Введите год издания: 123
>
>Введите автора книги: Введите количество страниц: 21
>
>Введите тираж: 123
>
>Введите год издания: 123
>
>Сведения о книгах в библиотеке: 
>
>
>Автор : Пушкин
>Количество страниц : 150
>Тираж : 234
>Год издания : 123
>
>
>Автор : 
>Количество страниц : 21
>Тираж : 123
>Год издания : 123
```

Насколько я знаю по своему прошлому опыту в плюсах, то туда просто попадал \n и я его просто игнорировал, но что делать в Java? Буду рад помощи опытных людей)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же считываете конец строки после "количество книг":

```
        System.out.print("Введите год издания: ");
        book[i].setYearPublishing(scan.nextInt());
        scan.nextLine(); // <--
```

Comment: Да, проблему я решил, просто добавив в начало цикла scan.nextLine();